# What are the titles of the short stories about Drizzt?

Tags: short-stories, forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

I know there are some short stories about [Drizzt Do'Urden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drizzt_Do%27Urden) out there.  I have read most of the books, but I would like to read the short stories too.

Any idea what the titles are (and info on where I can find them would be great too).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They've released an anthology *[The Collected Stories: The Legend of Drizzt](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1215210)* that contains nearly all of the Drizzt short stories.  Capsule descriptions are available on the [Forgotten Realms fandom page](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/The_Collected_Stories:_The_Legend_of_Drizzt_Anthology).

- The First Notch
- Dark Mirror
- The Third Level
- Guenhwyvar
- The Curious Sword
- Wickless in the Nether
- The Dowery
- Comrades at Odds
- If Ever They Happened Upon My Lair
- Bones and Stones
- Iruladoon
- The Legend He Goes

Comment: Do you happen to know which ones are not included?

Answer (score 7):

According to Wikipedia:

> Drizzt's story is told in Salvatore's
>   fantasy novels in The Icewind Dale
>   Trilogy, The Dark Elf Trilogy, the
>   Legacy of the Drow series, the Paths
>   of Darkness series, The Hunter's
>   Blades Trilogy, the Transitions
>   series, and the Neverwinter Trilogy,
>   **as well as in the short stories "The
>   Dowry," "Dark Mirror", and "Comrades
>   at Odds".**

And [this site](http://www.o-love.net/realms/ro_dri.html) seems to have info on all the books